# Get the first value from api request in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my react js application i use react-select => library.
https://react-select.com/home#getting-started

```js
import "./styles.css";
import Select from 'react-select'
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState();
 
  useEffect(() => {
    const response = fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => setState(json?.map((i) => {
      return {label: i.name, value: i.name}
    })))
  },[])
  console.log(state?.[0])
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Select
      defaultValue={state?.[0]} //expect the first value that comes from back-end
      options={state} 
      /> 
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

How you can notice i set as initial value the first value that comes from api `defaultValue={state?.[0]}`, but the value does not appear as default value, even in the console.log it appears. I assume that this happens because of `undefined` value on the first render, so in the first render `state?.[0]` is undefined, but after that the value appears in the console. How to get the initial value inside the select? 
 demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-keldysh-6xynq?file=/src/App.js:0-705

Comment: I don't think you saved your codesandbox link. it's showing the default starter code

Comment: @azium i saved now

Comment: great. @CHess answer is exactly right. because it doesn't "update" the default value because it keeps whatever it had from the first render. putting `if (!state) return null` fixes it

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the `useEffect` makes the API call **after** the first render. For most cases, this is a good thing, as it allows you render content, such as a loading spinner, while you are waiting for the API call to finish:

```js
export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState();
 
  useEffect(() => {
    const response = fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => setState(json?.map((i) => {
      return {label: i.name, value: i.name}
    })))
  },[])

  if (!state) {
      // you can display a loading spinner here if you want
      return null;
  }

  // Once we've reached this point on subsequent renders, state should be defined
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Select
      defaultValue={state.[0]} //expect the first value that comes from back-end
      options={state} 
      /> 
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Also note that because you are using `defaultValue`, it is essential that you have state defined *at the time the Select component is initially rendered/mounted* as subsequent changes that you send to `defaultValue` will not affect the current value (as the value was already "defaulted" to undefined).